# Linear independence in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1,...,v_k$ be vectors whose entries are all in $\{ 0, 1 \}$. These vectors can be considered both as elements of $\Bbb{Z}_2^n = \{0,1\}^n$ (with modulo 2 addition), and as elements of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (with regular addition).

Question: Is it true that $v_1,...,v_k$ are linearly independent with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (modulo 2 addition) $\Leftrightarrow v_1,...,v_k$ are linearly independent with respect to $\mathbb{R}$?
If not, is either direction true?

Comment: But $\mathbf Z_2$ is not a subfield of $\mathbf R$!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Notice that I assumed that $v_1,...,v_k$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ in either direction.

Comment: But $\Bbb Z_2$ is not even a **subset** of $\Bbb R$!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since these vectors have entries in $\{ 0, 1 \}$, it follows that any linear dependence of such vectors over $\Bbb{R}$ is actually (up to a constant multiple) a linear dependence over $\Bbb{Q}$, which can easily be turned into a linear dependence over $\Bbb{Z}$ by clearing denominators, and then by reducing mod $2$ can be turned into a linear dependence over $\Bbb{Z}_2$. *(If this linear dependence over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is initially trivial, that means the $\Bbb{Z}$-coefficients of the original linear dependence all had a factor of $2$ in them to begin with, which may be cancelled out; if the resulting linear dependence over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is still trivial, we repeat as necessary until not all the $\Bbb{Z}$-coefficients are even, at which point we get the desired nontrivial linear dependence relation over $\Bbb{Z}_2$.)*

But the other direction isn't true: the vectors $[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ (their sum is $[0, 0, 0, 0]$), but linearly independent over $\Bbb{R}$.